# Extract a single line string having "foo: XXXX"

Tags: ruby

I have a file with one or more key:value lines, and I want to pull a key:value out if key=foo. How can I do this?

I can get as far as this:

```
if File.exist?('/file_name')
  content = open('/file_name').grep(/foo:??/)
```

I am unsure about the grep portion, and also once I get the content, how do I extract the value?

Comment: Do you want to just get the value, or remove this entry from the file?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am looking for just the value if the 'foo' key exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People like to slurp the files into memory, which, if the file will always be small, is a reasonable solution. However, slurping isn't scalable, and the practice can lead to excessive CPU and I/O waits as content is read.

Instead, because you could have multiple hits in a file, and you're comparing the content line-by-line, read it line-by-line. Line I/O is very fast and avoids the scalability problems. Ruby's [`File.foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach) is the way to go:

```
File.foreach('path/to/file') do |li|
  puts $1 if li[/foo:\s*(\w+)/]
end
```

Because there are no samples of actual key/value pairs, we're shooting in the dark for valid regex patterns, but this is the basis for how I'd solve the problem.

Comment: Doesn't `foreach` I/O have the same problems with disk, only slightly less severe?

Comment: `foreach` doesn't slurp the file, it reads line-by-line, so its impact is minimal. `read` returns the file as a string or as many bytes as you told it to, requiring you to find line-ends and deal with partial lines, `readlines` reads the file and returns an array -- either way they've read the entire file into Ruby's memory all at once. The OS underneath buffers the I/O, so there is some read-ahead with `foreach` but nothing like you'd see trying to `read` or `readline` a 10GB file.

Comment: 10GB file is a pretty extreme case. :) I, for some reason, assumed that the OP is trying to read a config file. Config files are usually small. In this case the difference should be negligible.

Comment: 10GB is common around here because we have lots of software spewing lots of syslogs records. The OP doesn't specify what type of file it is, just that he's trying to handle key/value pairs. It could be almost any filetype. It also makes a big difference what the hosting machine is. A small host can grunt badly if it's RAM limited. I've seen minis stop periodically when reading 4GB files, which made me sensitive to the slurping issue.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is not correct. It is. I just had wrong assumptions :)

Comment: @theTinMan   Although my intended purpose was just for a small config file, which I didn't convey, your thorough explanation expanded my Ruby knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend to read the file into array and select only lines you need:

```
regex = /\A\s?key\s?:/
results = File.readlines('file').inject([]) do |f,l|
  l =~ regex ? f << "key = %s" % l.sub(regex, '') : f
end
```

this will detect lines starting with `key:` and adding them to results like `key = value`,
where `value` is the portion going after `key:`

so if you have a file like this:

```
key:1
foo
key:2
bar
key:3
```

you'll get results like this:

```
key = 1
key = 2
key = 3
```

makes sense?

Comment: I am using this file to store key:value configuration information, so how would you change your answer to simply use the last key:value where key=foo (since we can only have one value for a key)?

Comment: oh, i inverted it :) sec, updating

Comment: The file will have lines (separated by \n) of "foo:bar\nsomethingelse:else\n"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IO.readlines('key_values.txt').find_all{|line| line.match('key1')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value = File.open('/file_name').read.match("key:(.*)").captures[0] rescue nil
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.read('file_name')[/foo: (.*)/, 1]
#=> XXXX
```

Comment: This is definitely the shortest and seems to do the job.